BASH variables and curl
Can somebody please help me understand why the second command works as expect, but the first doesn't.
# first
SESSION=$(curl http://172.21.0.4:4444/status 2>&1 | grep sessionId | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d "\r\n\","); echo $SESSION; curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/$SESSION

# second
SESSION=$(curl http://172.21.0.4:4444/status 2>&1 | grep sessionId | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d "\r\n\","); echo $SESSION; curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/$(echo $SESSION)

First command results in
1f7838f7-c2ff-4d5a-90c1-e3ad89e74159
{
  "value": {
    "message": "Unable to find session with ID: \nBuild info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.0-27-generic', java.version: '17.0.10'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "stacktrace": 
    ..
    ..
    "error": "invalid session id"
  }
}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1f7838f7-c2ff-4d5a-90c1-e3ad89e74159

The second command works as expected
1f7838f7-c2ff-4d5a-90c1-e3ad89e74159
{"value":null}

I'm not sure if relevant, but this is via ssh on a remote machine.
Thank you.
EDIT: what I have tried.
spinning up a local http server with python.
Its a different environment but version #1 seems to work
just fine.
$ python3 -m http.server 9000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 9000 (http://0.0.0.0:9000/) ...
..
..
SESSION=bc8bcf9f-a901-440b-af9a-2da8a7fe6f2e
..
$ echo $SESSION
bc8bcf9f-a901-440b-af9a-2da8a7fe6f2e
..
$ curl localhost:9000/test/$SESSION
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 404</p>
        <p>Message: File not found.</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 404 - Nothing matches the given URI.</p>
    </body>
</html>
..
# python http server log
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2024 12:20:38] "GET /test/bc8bcf9f-a901-440b-af9a-2da8a7fe6f2e HTTP/1.1" 404 -


EDIT2:
output from curl http://172.21.0.4:4444/status added below.
Command #2 already gets me what I need, this is just me
being curious as to what the difference might be.
Without the stderr redirection I get this
$ curl http://10.10.14.70:8000/status | grep sessionID
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   418  100   418    0     0   1620      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1626

$ curl http://172.21.0.4:4444/status
{
  "value": {
    "ready": false,
    "message": "Selenium Grid not ready.",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": "0b1917b4-8a51-4af8-8fe7-e21ebc1f7d0e",
        "uri": "http:\u002f\u002f172.21.0.4:4444",
        "maxSessions": 1,
        "osInfo": {
          "arch": "amd64",
          "name": "Linux",
          "version": "6.5.0-27-generic"
        },
        "heartbeatPeriod": 30000,
        "availability": "UP",
        "version": "4.19.1 (revision abe0ee07dc)",
        "slots": [
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "0b1917b4-8a51-4af8-8fe7-e21ebc1f7d0e",
              "id": "c0508b7d-84ce-48d5-bfe8-7f5ae3ee89f1"
            },
            "lastStarted": "2024-05-04T14:58:20.936580226Z",
            "session": {
              "capabilities": {
                "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
                "browserName": "firefox",
                "browserVersion": "124.0.2",
                "moz:accessibilityChecks": false,
                "moz:buildID": "20240401114208",
                "moz:debuggerAddress": "127.0.0.1:14907",
                "moz:geckodriverVersion": "0.34.0",
                "moz:headless": false,
                "moz:platformVersion": "6.5.0-27-generic",
                "moz:processID": 431,
                "moz:profile": "\u002ftmp\u002frust_mozprofileu9zHDw",
                "moz:shutdownTimeout": 60000,
                "moz:webdriverClick": true,
                "moz:windowless": false,
                "pageLoadStrategy": "normal",
                "platformName": "linux",
                "proxy": {
                },
                "se:bidiEnabled": false,
                "se:cdp": "ws:\u002f\u002f172.21.0.4:4444\u002fsession\u002fb67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9\u002fse\u002fcdp",
                "se:cdpVersion": "85.0",
                "se:noVncPort": 7900,
                "se:vnc": "ws:\u002f\u002f172.21.0.4:4444\u002fsession\u002fb67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9\u002fse\u002fvnc",
                "se:vncEnabled": true,
                "se:vncLocalAddress": "ws:\u002f\u002f172.21.0.4:7900",
                "setWindowRect": true,
                "strictFileInteractability": false,
                "timeouts": {
                  "implicit": 0,
                  "pageLoad": 300000,
                  "script": 30000
                },
                "unhandledPromptBehavior": "dismiss and notify"
              },
              "sessionId": "b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9",
              "start": "2024-05-04T14:58:20.936580226Z",
              "stereotype": {
                "browserName": "firefox",
                "browserVersion": "124.0",
                "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                  "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002ffirefox"
                },
                "platformName": "linux",
                "se:noVncPort": 7900,
                "se:vncEnabled": true
              },
              "uri": "http:\u002f\u002f172.21.0.4:4444"
            },
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "firefox",
              "browserVersion": "124.0",
              "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002ffirefox"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


So, is it Bash or a POSIX shell ("sh")? Please remove the faulty tag. Also, is curl actually relevant here?

sorry, which faulty tag do you mean? it's bash (echo $SHELL -> /bin/bash.). I'm not sure if curl is relevant here, but I would have expected for both commands to do the same thing.

echo is not a reliable way to examine the value of a variable (especially when passed unquoted). try something like printf '%q\n' "$SESSION"

[edit] your question to show the output of curl http://172.21.0.4:4444/status so we can see what SESSION contains and help you extract just the session ID from the curl output as piping that to grep+cut+tr is not a good approach. Also, are you sure you want to add any stderrr being output from that curl into the stout you're then trying to extract a sessionId from (and presumably discard any of that stderr text)? Seems like that'd hide possible errors and make that extraction part fragile.

printf '%q\n' "$SESSION"; outputs
\ b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9
(on a new line) Is that backlash the problem, or merely a side effect of your printf command?

It means that SESSION starts with a space. That will cause curl to receive two arguments: curl http://host/[ ]session ([ ] denotes the space). echo [ ]session will simply ignore the space. Another way to easily find out: printf '[%s]' "$SESSION" or echo "[$SESSION]". You will see the space printed after the opening bracket. The rule is really simple: ALWAYS quote your parameters when expanding (this would have gotten you a different error with your command, but probably had made it easier to spot the mistake). Also set -x can really be helpful when troubleshooting shell errors.

Use jq to parse json instead of grep

And there are tools to parse JSON (jq). Using grep+cut+tr is really brittle and will lead exactly to the problems that you are encountering. "sessionId": "b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9" has a space after the : (your field delimiter with cut), and you never remove it. Use the right tool for the job and you can avoid such issues.

thanks knittl that explains the behaviour. using jq for some reason didn't cross my mind. How can I accept this answer?

@sven you can't, because it wasn't an answer; it was a comment. I have now written a full answer.

Attempting to parse JSON with grep+cut or anything that wasn't built to handle JSON is futile.
Running the following line through your pipeline grep sessionId | cut -d ":" -f2 | tr -d "\r\n\",":
"sessionId": "b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9",

will print  b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9 with a leading space character.
Your next mistake was to expand unquoted parameters.
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/$SESSION

will expand to:
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/ b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9

can you see the space?
However, running
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/$(echo $SESSION)

will expand to
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/$(echo  b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9)

can you still see the space?
Which will then expand to:
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/b67e09ac-ef3f-4b01-8aba-353436770fc9

It is crucial to quote parameters when expanding to avoid all sorts of surprises (field splitting, pathname expansion).
But for your concrete problem, the best action to take is not to parse JSON with tools that were never meant to parse JSON. Use tools built specifically for parsing JSON, such as jq:
session="$(… | jq -r '.sessionId')"

(yes, those quotes are redundant, but it's a good habit to always quote expansions)
The rules which expansions occur in which order are specified in section 2.6 Word Expansions of the POSIX standard.
